# VBA loop throught each cell to copy files

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel file where columns (icol) each cells contains a path of some files like this :

```
             column A                         column B          column c
P:\Desktop\Source\Test1-folder\file1.txt       empty column     P:\Desktop\Source\Test1-folder\filetest.txt            
P:\Desktop\Source\Test1-folder\file2.txt        .....
```

and I need to loop through these cells to copy files from the cells into destination folder, but i couldn't succeed .Can anyone help how to do it?

```
Dim strSlash As String, destinationFolder As String
Dim lastcolumn As Long, icol As Long, lastLigne As Long
Dim rngCell As Range, rngFiles As Range
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
destinationFolder = "P:\Desktop\folderdestination"
Dim maListe As Object
Dim workboo As Workbook
Dim worksh As Worksheet

Set workboo = Workbooks.Open(P:\Desktop\Source\excelfile.xlsx)
Set worksh = workboo.Worksheets("path_files")

lastcolumn = Cells(1, Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
     If Dir(destinationFolder, 16) = "" Then MkDir (destinationFolder)
         For icol = 1 To lastcolumn Step 2
            lastLigne = Cells(Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Row
            Set rngFiles = Cells(1, icol).Resize(lastLigne)
                 For Each rngCell In rngFiles.Cells
                 If Dir(rngCell.Value) <> "" Then 
                 strFile = Right(rngCell.Value, Len(rngCell.Value) - InStrRev(rngCell.Value, "\"))
                 If Dir(destinationFolder & "\" & Left(strFile, 5) , 16) = "" Then
                  FSO.CopyFile rngCell.Value, destinationFolder & "\" & Left(strFile, 5)           
                   End If
                 End If
                  Next rngCell
          Next icol
```

end sub

Comment: You have a whole load of syntax errors in there.  The destinationFolder needs to be inside quotes, you never declared or set dercol to anything,  you appear to be using an FSO object without ever creating it or setting it, you're missing a `Next` for the first `For` loop...  Have you definitely posted ALL the code? It seems like there's a fair bit missing...

Comment: @Dave i edit it because i put at first just a part of the code

Comment: Ok.  First, correct the declaration of `destination folder` to `destinationFolder`, variables can't have spaces in them.  Then replace any instance of `worksh` with `ws` as that's what you declared and set to be the worksheet.  I still don't see dercol (in the line `For k = 1 To dercol`) defined anywhere so that's going to initialise to zero and prevent the loop executing.  You are still missing a `Next` as you have two `For` loops and each needs its own `Next`...

Comment: And put Option Explicit at the very top of the page; this will tell VBA to ensure that you've declared all variables in use.

Comment: i put just a part of the code because i still have code below in my program . but the main problem is that it doesn't copy any of those files @Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited** to add a check for source file existence

this should do

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

    Dim strSlash As String, destinationFolder As String
    Dim lastcolumn As Long, icol As Long, lastLigne As Long
    Dim rngCell As Range, rngFiles As Range
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject

    strSlash = "\"
    destinationFolder = "P:\Desktop\folderdestination"
    lastcolumn = Cells(1, Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For icol = 1 To lastcolumn Step 2
        lastLigne = Cells(Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngFiles = Cells(1, icol).Resize(lastLigne)
        For Each rngCell In rngFiles.Cells
            If Dir(rngCell.Value) <> "" Then '<~~ check if the source file is actually there!
                If Dir(destinationFolder & "\" & Right(rngCell.Value, Len(rngCell.Value) - InStrRev(rngCell.Value, strSlash)), 16) = "" Then
                    FSO.CopyFile rngCell.Value, destinationFolder & "\" & Right(rngCell.Value, Len(rngCell.Value) - InStrRev(rngCell.Value, strSlash))
                End If
            End If
        Next rngCell
    Next icol

End Sub
```

but it could still be improved to a good extent, exploiting FileSystemObject more thoroughly (which of course needs adding reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" library: Tools->References and then scroll down List Box and select "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" checkbox)

Comment: thank you ! but one last thing , it doesn't copy the files in column C , it execute only for column A , althought it isn't the last column

Comment: the loop iterates over columns with uneven index (i.e. 1, 3, 5, ...), from column "A" (index 1) to the last with non empty cell in row 1. From your question I'd assume that `lastcolumn` returns 2, as if column "C" hadn't any value in its first row: is it like that? check for `lastcolumn` returned value

Comment: no , the problem is that it returns 3 , but it don't copy files in column c which is strange

Comment: step through code and use Immediate Window to query variables values. for instance once it begins the 2nd `iCol` iteration check what value `lastLigne` is set to. should it be a "vaild" one (say: 5) then step into `For Each rngCell` loop and check for both `Address` and `Value` property of each `rngCell` object. if still ok, then check for `Dir(destinationFolder ...` return value. Most probably here you'll find the issue since you're using `Dir()` function with a `16` "Attribute" which stands for  `vbDirectory` i.e.: "Specifies directories or folders in addition to files with no attributes"

Comment: but there was an error in my code: I didn't change the first occurrence of `(Len(rngCell.Value) - InStrRev(rngCell.Value, strSlash))` with `Right(rngCell.Value, Len(rngCell.Value) - InStrRev(rngCell.Value, strSlash))` as i did with its 2nd occurrence (right after!). see edited code

Comment: @JeanLo: did you get through it?

Comment: thak you again for your reply , in fact the first occurence works perfectly , but once it pass to the column 3 (C) an error : **Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5) **     in line :  FSO.CopyFile rngCell.Value, destinationFolder & "\" & Right(rngCell.Value, Len  @user3598756

Comment: still the same problem , it just don't want to copy files in the column C . can you help me with this please ?

Comment: I added a `New` keyword in the declaration of `FSO` object and a check for existence of source files. see edited answer

Comment: @JeanLo: is it ok now?

Comment: still the same problem ... it doesn t pass to the next column @user3598756

Comment: post the minimum "not working" excel file excerpt. you could upload it or edit your post showing just the rows and columns to copiypast into any excel file and produce the problem you're dealing with

Comment: i did @user3598756

Comment: I mean data too. for instancepost the first 3 rows of the first 3 columns that if alone put into an excel file would have the code you posted reproduce the issue you're actually struggling with

Comment: i tried to post it but it didn 't work , can i send to you on mail or something please ? @user3598756

Comment: just edit your question and show the 3x3 range content that alone causes the issue

Comment: i did . well it seems everything is okay but still problem in column C , maybe because it has a different lastligne ?

Comment: if you used the exact code you put in the edited question, then there's my `destinationFolder` initialization, which cannot be valid for your needs. you must uncomment the `destinationFolder = "P:\Desktop\folderdestination"` and comment (better, delete) the line after it

Comment: in the code i put the "" it s just the edit question that i forgot them . but the problem still the same :s

Comment: either we're on the same page or it's a time loss. so please have both your question code edited as you _actually_ use it and minimum data that, alone, throws the issue

Comment: this is the code that i use and it doesn ' t work on going to the other column .. it still the same problem unfortunately .. but thanks for your help , please if you knew how to do it correct it to me